# ClassNotFoundException: org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager

Tags: java, weblogic, iso8583, jpos, oracle-service-bus

When runing JPOS lib on eclipse it is running fine. But when running on oracle service bus java callout it is giving following error.

[image: JPOS Exception]

Comment: You should be sure that you have all jars in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: It is working fine when runing on eclipse (OEP) the exception is comming when the jar file of our project is running on weblogic

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637241/compatibility-of-jpos-and-weblogic**

Comment: In above link exception is different

Comment: Classpath in eclipse has nothing to do wit classpath in oracle service bus. How are you adding the jpos jars to the classpath? Also sharin an image as part of the question where the only thing you see is text, doesn't help. Pleas improve your question pasting the actual text.

Comment: Problem doesn't seem jpos related at all, you are just using a library without including it in the classpath, I don't know anything about oracle web services but there must be somewhere where you can say where the libraries are located. For a proper question you should add the code tha is launching the exception as well

Comment: Yes it  is not related to JPOS. I need to know how to add JPOS.jar to OSB(Oracle Service Bus) . so in JAVA callout exception ll not come

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4136106?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

By adding dependency it is runing .
https://community.oracle.com/thread/4136106